# Format date time field to specific time with AMPscript in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime, timezone, time

I have a question; we are trying to send an appointment confirmation through Journey Builder. Now we are struggling to get the time right. It looks like there is added 1 and sometimes 2 minutes to the time. What are we doing wrong?

The data in the source data extension is:
`1/11/2019 11:00:00 AM`

We tried to format this into 3 desired values the following way:

```
%%[  
SET @StartDate = FormatDate(Event:StartDateTime, "dd MMMMM YYYY",, "nl-NL")  
SET @StartDay = FormatDate(Event:StartDateTime, "ddddd",,"nl-NL")  
SET @StartTime = FormatDate(Event:StartDateTime, "HH:mm",,"nl-NL")   
]%%
```

In the email it displayed the following time at the `@StartTime 11:01`, there is added an extra minute. Does someone know why?

Comment: you could potentially try using DatePart() function to retrieve Hours and Minutes, but not sure if it will cause same issue - that is a weird bug. I would definitely report that to SFMC .  Have you tried setting the `Event:StartDateTime` to a var and using that? perhaps there is some miscommunication between the function and the data pull from SFSC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tested it and it doesn't work, strange.

You can use Format instead of FormatDate like:

```
Format(Event:StartDateTime, 'HH:mm', 'Date', 'nl-NL')
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find a documentation of Event:StartDateTime? Is it activity specfic inside the journeybuilder (aka when the email activity has been reached) or is it the time when the journey triggered or even something different? Or is it a EventDescription when you use an "Event" as entrysource rather than an dataextension? Or is it something from other platforms like Salescloud?

Comment: I couldn't find a detailed document but it is from SalesCloud and you can see this link to get a visual: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000Dju0QAC

Comment: @SelimSevim, thanks! Fixed the issue by using format. The problem was the FormatDate function.